# Proper procedure to import existing RESX files into a C#/WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, resources, resx

I have my auto generated Resource.resx file set up with keys and strings. I also have three other resx files for German, French and Spanish given to me from translators. I'm not able to get the localization functioning and I suspect that the resx files aren't being called correctly. I added them to the project by dragging them into the solution explorer under "Properties". I have a nagging suspicion that just dragging them in isn't creating the proper connections behind the scene.

Now It's totally possible my issue lies somewhere else. If anyone can tell me whether it's ok to add resource files this way or if not, what the correct way is, it would save me tons of time spent chasing my tail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Resx files in Visual Studio include a special tool which is run at build time and translates them into embedded resources. Right-click your original VS-created resx file and click Properties. You should see Build Tool or something similar. Also note the resource type (Embedded, etc.). Make sure that you match these settings for your manually added files.

Once this is set up, you will need to use the `CurrentUICulture` property to tell .NET to pick up the appropriate resources. You can choose to change the culture/language at install-time or run-time. Here is a comprehensive tutorial which describes the various options available to you:

[WPF Localization Using RESX Files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files)

That said, as a best practice, translated Resx files are generally deployed as **satellite assemblies**. The main application DLL/EXE contains only the language neutral resources file. Other resource files are compiled into separate assemblies and deployed side-by-side with specific naming conventions. This allows you to dynamically add translations, localizations, etc. even after the application is deployed. Here's an introduction: [Packaging and Deploying Resources in Desktop Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618.aspx)